# JavaScript error: "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

It looks like "$smth is not a function" is a very common problem with JavaScript, yet after looking through quite a few threads I still cannot understand what is causing it in my case.

I have a custom object, defined as:

```
function Scorm_API_12() {
var Initialized = false;

function LMSInitialize(param) {
    errorCode = "0";
    if (param == "") {
        if (!Initialized) {
            Initialized = true;
            errorCode = "0";
            return "true";
        } else {
            errorCode = "101";
        }
    } else {
        errorCode = "201";
    }
    return "false";
}

// some more functions, omitted.
}

var API = new Scorm_API_12();
```

Then in a different script I am trying to use this API in the following way:

```
var API = null;

function ScormProcessInitialize(){
    var result;

    API = getAPI();

    if (API == null){
        alert("ERROR - Could not establish a connection with the API.");
        return;
    }

    // and here the dreaded error pops up
    result = API.LMSInitialize("");

    // more code, omitted
    initialized = true;
}
```

The getAPI() stuff, looks like this:

```
var findAPITries = 0;

function findAPI(win)
{
   // Check to see if the window (win) contains the API
   // if the window (win) does not contain the API and
   // the window (win) has a parent window and the parent window
   // is not the same as the window (win)
   while ( (win.API == null) &&
           (win.parent != null) &&
           (win.parent != win) )
   {
      // increment the number of findAPITries
      findAPITries++;

      // Note: 7 is an arbitrary number, but should be more than sufficient
      if (findAPITries > 7)
      {
         alert("Error finding API -- too deeply nested.");
         return null;
      }

      // set the variable that represents the window being
      // being searched to be the parent of the current window
      // then search for the API again
      win = win.parent;
   }
   return win.API;
}

function getAPI()
{
   // start by looking for the API in the current window
   var theAPI = findAPI(window);

   // if the API is null (could not be found in the current window)
   // and the current window has an opener window
   if ( (theAPI == null) &&
        (window.opener != null) &&
        (typeof(window.opener) != "undefined") )
   {
      // try to find the API in the current window�s opener
      theAPI = findAPI(window.opener);
   }
   // if the API has not been found
   if (theAPI == null)
   {
      // Alert the user that the API Adapter could not be found
      alert("Unable to find an API adapter");
   }
   return theAPI;
}
```

Now, the API is *probably* found, because I do not get the "Unable to find..." message, the code proceeds to try to initialize it. But firebug tells me `API.LMSInitialize is not a function`, and if I try to debug it with `alert(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(API));`, it gives me a blank alert.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you get when you just do a `console.log(API)` right after the `API = getAPI();`?

Comment: please can you let me know what you want to do after initilization..

Comment: I got that error because I had a circular dependency. Maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: I got that error because I had a circular dependency. Created a `abc_2.js` file to fix it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your `LMSInitialize` function is declared inside `Scorm_API_12` function. So it can be seen only in `Scorm_API_12` function's scope.

If you want to use this function like `API.LMSInitialize("")`, declare `Scorm_API_12` function like this:

```
function Scorm_API_12() {
var Initialized = false;

this.LMSInitialize = function(param) {
    errorCode = "0";
    if (param == "") {
        if (!Initialized) {
            Initialized = true;
            errorCode = "0";
            return "true";
        } else {
            errorCode = "101";
        }
    } else {
        errorCode = "201";
    }
    return "false";
}

// some more functions, omitted.
}

var API = new Scorm_API_12();
```

Comment: can I call this.LMSInitialize(parm) in other this.AfterLMSInitialize = function(){} ??

Answer (score 32):

For more **generic** advice on debugging this kind of problem MDN have a good article [TypeError: "x" is not a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function):

> It was attempted to call a value like a function, but the value is not
>   actually a function. Some code expects you to provide a function, but
>   that didn't happen.
>
> Maybe there is a typo in the function name? Maybe the object you are
>   calling the method on does not have this function? For example,
>   JavaScript objects have no map function, but JavaScript Array object
>   do.

Basically the object (all functions in js are also objects) does not exist where you think it does. This could be for **numerous** reasons **including**(not an extensive list):

- Missing script library
- Typo
- The function is within a scope that you currently do not have access to, e.g.:

```js
var x = function(){
   var y = function() {
      alert('fired y');
   }
};
    
//the global scope can't access y because it is closed over in x and not exposed
//y is not a function err triggered
x.y();
```

- Your object/function does not have the function your calling:

```js
var x = function(){
   var y = function() {
      alert('fired y');
   }
};
    
//z is not a function error (as above) triggered
x.z();
```

Comment: I'd like to add: naming a local variable the same thing as a function, so when you call `showOrderForm()` the type of `showOrderForm` is a boolean.

Comment: seriously you gave a bit of lifesaver advice about the function as something is waiting for the function but it's getting the object or array that great advice!

Answer (score 9):

I also hit this error. In my case the root cause was async related (during a codebase refactor):  An asynchronous function that builds the object to which the "not a function" function   belongs was not awaited, and the subsequent attempt to invoke the function throws the error, example below:

```
const car = carFactory.getCar();
car.drive() //throws TypeError: drive is not a function
```

The fix was:

```
const car = await carFactory.getCar();
car.drive()
```

Posting this incase it helps anyone else facing this error.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the popular answers above, if you are using a services or helper functions file and doing an `export` on the functions that you will later `import` in your project.

Make sure that the function name you are importing matches the exact name of the function being exported from the services, helper, or utils file - and that the function actually exists in the right file! I got stuck on this error and was debugging for a few hours, getting nowhere until I found this out.

Answer (score 1):

I got that error because I had a circular dependency as mentioned already in comments by @SadSeven and @Manohar Reddy Poreddy.  Just to be more specific, I had two modules called ModuleA and ModuleB.

ModuleA contained a line:

```
      const FB = require("./ModuleB");
```

And ModuleB contained a line:

```
      const FA = require("./ModuleA");
```

This caused the error: "is not a function" during execution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after a ton of stackoverflowing I saw **what a function thing would go with here...** it was merely a silly typo ,  I forgot to put **$** in start of the next line's instruction:

```
 function o_chir(id,nom) {
        _id_ochirish = id
        _nom= nom  
//here it threw that "Uncaught TypeError: nom is not a function"       
        ('#nom').val(s_)
        $('#o_chir').modal('show')
    }
```

and PHPStorm didnt give any warning

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Next.js. On _app.tsx I forgot to wrap the Component with the AuthProvider where I had all the Authentication functions.

Answer (score -1):

I received this error when I copied a class object incorrectly using JSON.parse and JSON.stringify() which removed the function like:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  // Method
  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);

console.log('area of square: ', square.calcArea());

const squareCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(square));

// Will throw an exception since calcArea() is no longer function 
console.log('area of square copy: ', squareCopy.calcArea());
```

Comment: This isn't the [correct way to clone a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474986/how-to-clone-a-javascript-es6-class-instance)

Comment: @Liam I was trying to communicate that I had cloned a class the wrong way. I was not trying to say that this is the way you should clone a class. I'll update my answer to make that more clear.