# Uncaught TypeError: .. is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to use d3.js to draw line chart.

### Javascript

```
function lineChart(){
    ...
}

function update(){
    ...
    var lineChart = lineChart()
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([2011, 2014]))
        .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1000000]));
    ...
}
```

But the console says that `Uncaught TypeError: lineChart is not a function`.
How to fix this?

Comment: use `var lineChartResult = lineChart()...`

Comment: Just change variable name. thats it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript error: "is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825071/javascript-error-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are shadowing your function.

This happens when you declare another variable/function with the same name of an upper one. What you should do is to give another name to the second one declaration just like @andlrc says in his comment.

```
var lineChartResult = lineChart()...
```

You can learn more about shadowing in here: [Setting & Shadowing Properties](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md#setting--shadowing-properties)

Answer (score 7):

If you declare a variable with the name of an existing function, that function is no longer available within that context (is *shadowed* by the variable). Change the name of the variable to avoid that naming collision.

This code is equivalente to yours, maybe you can see what is happening:

```
function lineChart() {...} //function declared

function update() {
    var lineChart; // variable created, its value is undefined
    lineChart=lineChart() // linechart is not a function, is an undefined value!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, if you don't want to change your variable name, is to qualify the method name with `this` to disambiguate it from the variable name that precedes it:

`var lineChart = this.lineChart()...`