# Slider is not a function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suddenly on my website, clickable buttons which makes the slider go to different values stopped working because of this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function

The main slider code works and an error does not popup saying slider is not a function for this: `

```
 $( "#test" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: minCoins,
      max: 100000,
      value: 2,
      step: 10000,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var slidVal = ui.value;
        if ( slidVal%10000 == 0 ){ // this condition because for each slide we are increasing the value by 1000
          slidValCm = slidVal;
           $("#noofCoins").html(numberWithCommas(slidValCm));
          document.getElementById('coinsBought').value = ($('#noofCoins').text());
          $('#quantity').val(); //just empty input for security purpose


    }

    for ( i = 0;i <= slidVal;i++ )
    {
     if ( i%10000 == 0 && i != 0){
            quant = quant+1;
       exactCoint = exactCoint+10000;
         costCoin = costCoin+costPair;
       costCoinFi = (costCoin*1).toFixed(2);
       $("#quant").html(quant);
       $('#quantity').val(parseInt(quant));
       $("#price-preview").html("<span class='money'>£"+costCoinFi+"</span>");
       Currency.convertAll(defaultCurrency, Currency.currentCurrency); 

      }

      if ( i == 0){
        $("#quant").html(0);
        $("#price-preview").html("<span class='money'>£"+costCoinFi+"</span>");
        Currency.convertAll(defaultCurrency, Currency.currentCurrency);
      }
    }

    costCoin = 0;
       quant = 0;
  }
});`
```

However, for the individual quick value buttons it doesn't update the slider position because it says slider is not a function. Example this is one of the event handlers for one of the buttons.

```
$("#20k").on('click', function(){
     var coinNum  = 20000;
     var totlCost = getCost(coinNum);
     var totquan  = (coinNum/rngCoins/10);
    $("#quant").html(totquan);
    $('#quantity').val(parseInt(totquan));
    $("#price-preview").html("<span class='money'>£"+totlCost+"</span>");
    $("#noofCoins").html("20,000");
    $("#test").slider('value', 20000);
    document.getElementById('coinsBought').value = ($('#noofCoins').text());
    Currency.convertAll(defaultCurrency, Currency.currentCurrency);
     });
```

This - `$("#test").slider('value', 20000);` - would be the problem of issue. Why is this? Thanks

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI?

Comment: Show your statement that includes the jQuery UI or whatever library that has slider().  That is probably missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript error: "is not a function"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825071/javascript-error-is-not-a-function)

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> Those are two that I have above the js code but the thing is the first section of code that says .slider in it works just not the one under the button click event handler

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup ^

Comment: Any Help? to solve

Answer (score -2):

$(selector).slider() is a jQuery UI function.

https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: He knows that and has the source included.