# $.notify is not a function with Bootstrap in MVC after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, notify

I want to show a notify when an ajax function completes. My ajax is good I just can't seem to get the notify to work. I have jquery and everything installed and I also have notify.js. From the Chrome console I came to know the below error

> Uncaught TypeError: $.notify is not a function

And also I am getting my ajax response fine. Below is the code for notifying,

```
@if (TempData.ContainsKey("SuccessMessage"))
{
    <script>
        $.notify({
            message: '@TempData["SuccessMessage"].ToString()'
        }, {
            type: 'success',
            delay: 7000,
        });
    </script>
}
```

And below is the references added for the same,

```
<script src="/bootstrap/js/notify.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if I am making any mistakes

Comment: Are you sure your local path is correct? The CDN link to notify.js also leads to a 404.

Comment: Do you need to load jquery before notify? Is it a dependency?

Comment: Yes @RoryMcCrossan CDN is leading to 404, Thanks for the same.And have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript error: "is not a function"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825071/javascript-error-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Or [TypeError: "x" is not a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Invert a declaration

```js
<script src="/scripts/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap/js/notify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was what in function `load()`, I loaded another `jquery.js`