# Node.js qrcode library issue

Tags: node.js

I have reinstalled my web app in a new server without changing anything and now I receive this error:

```
TypeError: QRCode.drawBitArray is not a function
```

why? i haven't change my code....

this is the library : https://github.com/simwood/node-qrcode

and yess, i have install all the dependencies.

alternatively, do I recommend libraries that return an array with the length of the line?

sorry for bad english(:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9825071/1531971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawBitArray` has been removed in the last version of `qrcode`.
The official repo seems to be [here](https://github.com/soldair/node-qrcode) and the last version with the function is `0.7.1`.

In the last version (at this time `1.4.4`) you can obtain the array of bits and the size returned by `drawBitArray` this way:

```
const myQrCode = qrcode.create("myContent")
const bits = new Uint8Array(myQrCode.modules.data)
const QrLineSize = myQrCode.modules.size
```

Answer (score 0):

run this `npm install --save node-qrcode`

if that doesnt work try deleting node_modules folder and running that command again.

also check the version of node-qrcode that are installed in your package.json file. make sure theyre consistant with eachother