# What is the replacement function for Contract.at in web3.js for including a contract?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, web3js

Getting this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: TestContract.at is not a function

I am implementing a sample contract on a test server using this code i got from a course which I'm doing on Blockchain

```
var TestContract =new web3.eth.Contract([
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_fName",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_age",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setInstructor",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getInstructor",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
])

var Test = TestContract.at('0xd1d0ba6a5af6bb66490d04b99f4955eb9c9fef36');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript error: "is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825071/javascript-error-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 2):

You can just add an address as the second parameter

```
var TestContract =new web3.eth.Contract([
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_fName",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_age",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setInstructor",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getInstructor",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
],'0xd1d0ba6a5af6bb66490d04b99f4955eb9c9fef36')
```

You can read more about the available parameters [there](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#properties)

Or you can add it via

```
TestContract.options.address = '0xd1d0ba6a5af6bb66490d04b99f4955eb9c9fef36'
```